# What is the meaning of 'screen' in this context?

Tags: translation, word-in-context

Tate and I started to make an anthology together. It was a very interesting year I spent with Tate and his wife. He’s a poet who writes in spurts, and he had about a third of a book. I was going to do a biography of Jonathan Edwards and he was going to write a novel, and our wives were going to write novels. Well, the wives just went humming away. “I’ve just finished three pages,” they’d say at the end of the day; and their books mounted up. But ours never did, though one morning Allen wrote four pages to his novel, very brilliant. **We were in a little study together separated by a screen**. I was heaping up books on Jonathan Edwards and taking notes, and getting more and more numb on the subject, looking at old leather-bound volumes on freedom of the will and so on, and feeling less and less a calling. And there we stuck. And then we decided to make an anthology together. We both liked rather formal, difficult poems, and we were reading particularly the sixteenth and seventeenth centuries. In the evening we’d read aloud, and we started a card catalog of what we’d make for the anthology. And then we started writing. It seems to me we took old models like Drayton’s Ode—Tate wrote a poem called “The Young Proconsuls of the Air” in that stanza. I think there’s a trick to formal poetry. Most poetry is very formal, but when a modern poet is formal he gets more attention for it than old poets did. Somehow we’ve tried to make it look difficult. For example, Shelley can just rattle off terza rima by the page, and it’s very smooth, doesn’t seem an obstruction to him—you sometimes wish it were more difficult. Well, someone does that today and in modern style it looks as though he’s wrestling with every line and may be pushed into confusion, as though he’s having a real struggle with form and content. Marks of that are in the finished poem. And I think both Tate and I felt that we wanted our formal patterns to seem a hardship and something that we couldn’t rattle off easily.

Comment: Firstly, have you looked up the word *screen* in a dictionary?  Secondly, what is the context of this sentence?  It often helps to have more context to understand the exact meaning of a word.

Comment: @stangdon ofcourse I do,but I didn't found a related meaning to this. This the whole pragraph

Comment: If you google "define screen", the very first thing that comes up is "a fixed or movable upright partition used to divide a room, to give shelter from drafts, heat, or light, or to provide concealment or privacy."  Does that help?

Comment: @stangdon do you think he is talking about seprated rooms? I thought that have a special meaning in poetry

Comment: I think he's talking about some kind of divider within the room.  They're sitting in one room, and there is a partition between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's a room divider. Usually a folding screen used to divide two parts of a room or separate a smaller part from the rest, maybe conceal something.
You've probably seen one type of it many times in movies or TV shows, usually a woman changes behind one.

Answer (score 2):

Considering it's in a study they probably mean a decorative folding room divider like this one.

I think your confusion is probably because "screen" has many meanings. But I think we can rule out a hanging mosquito net or a panel for projecting light onto.

[image: A room divider screen]